# Google+ required for Picasa Web Albums?

Tags: google-plus, picasa-web-albums

Do I now have to use Google Plus to load & view my Picasa web albums?

I can't find out how to NOT use Google+ when trying to view my web albums.

Comment: you can also access the Picasa web albums in Google+ by clicking on the photos in your profile

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to switch to Google+ (although you should probably start considering doing so - it is clear that most new work is going into Google+ Photos and PicasaWeb is on the way out).

You can go directly to https://picasaweb.google.com/?noredirect=1 and it will leave you at the PicasaWeb album page without trying to redirect you to Google+ Photos.